# ion-fab different position for ios and android

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, floating-action-button

I want to place a button at the bottom of the page (above the tabs). The position is different for ios and for android (8% in ios and 11% in android).
I tried to make different settings for ios and for md and it did not work. In addition, I searched in the Internet and did not find a solution. It is possible at all for ion-fab? And if yes so how?

html:

```
 <ion-fab>
      <button ion-fab class="circle (click)="func()">button name
      </button>
 </ion-fab>
```

scss:

```
  ion-fab {
    bottom: 11%;
    left: 33.3%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .circle {
    color: #494949;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    width: 138px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 2px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  }
```

Comment: Workaround would be to check in ts if the app is openend in ios and then in your html `[class]="isIOS ? 'circle ios' : 'circle android'"` and then style the `.circle.ios` and `.circle.android` differently

Comment: you can try `ion-fab.ios` and `ion-fab.md`. Both are classes added by the respective platforms. You will have to inspect to verify